# Where to specify non DB functions in laravel when using ORM?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example I have a table Shops.
So I have ORM model Shop.

I need a function to send email to shop owners.:

```
function sendEmail($body){
}
```

Now I want this Work:

```
Shop::find(1)->sendEmail('Email body to one shop')
Shop::all()->sendEmail('Send bulk email')
```

Where to put sendEmail function? in the ORM model?
What is the best-practive for that?

Comment: I think you're better off creating your own mailer class in line with following the single responsibility principle. I think you would just throw the method in the model though if you wanted it to work the way you've got the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a mail service. Ideally working towards an interface.

Something like:

```
$shop = Shop::where('postcode', '=', 44444)->first();
AppMailer::send($shop);
AppMailer::bulk(Shop::where('postcode', '=', 44444));
```

**Service method, over in your service class**

```
// Single send
function send(IMailable $mailable) 
{
    // do mail stuff here
    // the mail service doesn't even need to care if its 
    // eloquent or not
    $this->doSomething($mailable->email); 
}

// Bulk send
function bulk(Collection $mailables)
{
    foreach ($mailables as $mailable)
    {
        if($mailable instanceof IMailable) 
        {
            $this->send($mailable);
        }
    }

}
```

**IMailable, over in your IMailer interface class**

```
interface IMailable {
    public function getEmailAddress();
    public function getName();
}
```

**Shop class somewhere**

```
class Shop extends Eloquent implements IMailable {
    // bla bla your normal attributes for a shop

    // add some special attributes to statisfy the mailable contract
    public function getEmailAddress() 
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->streetNumber . ' ' . $this->streetName;
    }
}
```

The good thing about all this is that later if you want to email `Cafes` as well as `Shops` you just need to make sure your Cafe class implements `IMailable` and you are laughing all the way to the shop, and well cafe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work. But one problem. I want to be able to send bulk emails "Shop::all()->sendEmail". How I do that? your AppMailer class, gets only the first shop. How to write the "Send" function for that?

Comment: Updated. It just loops over the collection